# The security validation for this page is invalid. attach a file through php sharepoint API

Tags: php, sharepoint

I have created basic webtool for candidate information using `PHP Sharepoint API (Thybag)`.

I could do create the listitem. But I try to attach a file, i received this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error
>   (soap:Server) Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was
>   thrown.,more=Detailed: The security validation for this page is
>   invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try
>   your operation again.' in D:\wamp\www\jobs\SharePointAPI.php on line
>   1013.

I couldn't see any error report in github regards this.

This is code i try to execute: `$sp->addAttachment('applicant', 21, "files/PID.txt");`

all authentication process are done in while execute the PHP file.

Anybody can help this to resolve?

Comment: What version of sharepoint are you talking to? This may be a similar bug to https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API/issues/82

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue. The issue lies in this file

> PHPSharePointListsAPI/src/Thybag/Auth/SharePointOnlineAuth.php on line 22

Just replace line 22 with the below code :-

> $headers = array('SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"');

Hope that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Cool... it is working...I have already commented in github for your answer